# Android как собрать JAR библиотеку из GitHub

Tags: android, delphi, github

Есть библиотека https://github.com/mik3y/usb-serial-for-android как из нее собрать jar библиотеку
для подключения в проекты где нет gradle и maven (Например сборка проектов android на Delphi и т.д.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Wiki приведенного репозитория написано, что с помощью gradle вы можете собрать jar

> you need a jar file (e.g. for cordova) run gradle task `createFullJarRelease` and use **full.jar**

https://github.com/mik3y/usb-serial-for-android/wiki/Build-Variants#jar